# How to filter an arraylist by a char value that was input by a user

Tags: java, java-stream

Trying to filter an ArrayList of students by the first letter of the first name. The char value is user defined.

I've tried changing char to string and using the shows " " instead of char firstLetter.

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(students));

System.out.println("Please enter the first letter a students name: ");
firstLetter = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

Student student1 = student.stream().filter(x -> x.getFirstName().indexOf(firstLetter) == 0)
            .map(Student::getFirstName).findAny().orElse(Null);
```

The goal is to print a list of students from the array whose name starts with the letter entered by a user. Getting a char cannot be dereferenced error.

Comment: Your IDE probably gave you a warning on `firstLetter.equals(x.getFirstName())`. This comparison doesn't make much sense. Hint: get the first char/letter of first name.

Comment: `Student student = studentList.stream().filter(x -> firstLetter.equals(x.getFirstName()))
        .map(Student::getFirstName).findAny().orElse(Null);` is returning the type of `Student::getFirstName` (probably `String`), not `Student`

Comment: @Ezequiel does that mean I should be using (String::getFistName)? When I try that it creates an invalid method refrence.

Comment: That means the code does not compiles. To make it compilable your code should looks like ´String studentFirstName = student.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getFirstName().indexOf(firstLetter) == 0)
        .map(Student::getFirstName).findAny().orElse(null);´. anyway this is not what you expect. You are expecting a list of Student, so try with solutions provided below.

Answer (score 2):

You can instead use:

```
.filter(x -> x.getFirstName().startsWith(String.valueOf(firstLetter)))
```

and get rid of the `map`ping in use

```
.map(Student::getFirstName)
```

such that you don't have string in the resulting entity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `firstLetter` is not an object and therefore you can't call methods on it. What you can do is (Assuming `FirstName` is `Character` and therefore an object you can call methods on):

```java
Student student1 = student.stream()
                          .filter(x -> x.getFirstName().equals(firstLetter))
                          .map(Student::getFirstName)
                          .findAny()
                          .orElse(Null);
```

Or even better (using Unboxing):

```java
Student student1 = student.stream()
                          .filter(x -> firstLetter == x.getFirstName())
                          .map(Student::getFirstName)
                          .findFirst()
                          .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//List<Student> studentL = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(students));

System.out.println("Please enter the first letter a students name: ");
String prefix = keyboard.nextLine(); //.substring(0, 1);

List<Student> foundStudents = Stream.of(students
        .filter(x -> x.getFirstName().startsWith(prefix))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getFirstName)
             .thenComparing(Studen::getLastName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
 System.out.printf("  %25s %s%n", "First_name", "Last_name");
 for (Student foundStudent : foundStudents) {
     System.out.printf("- %25s %s%n",
             foundStudent.getFirstName(), foundStudent.getLastName());
 }
 System.out.printf("%d Students found.%n", foundStudents.size());
```

This prints a list of found students. Limiting to a single letter seems too restrictive.

The **error** was for the char firstLetter using equals:

```
firstLetter.equals(x.getFirstName())
```

Which should have been (assuming first name is always non-empty):

```
firstLetter == x.getFirstName.charAt(0)
```